# Batch size used by MC connect to sync IER records

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We are having issues with the number of individual email result records the MC connect integration is creating. We have searched in the documentation for the syncing batch size but couldn't find it.

Help will be appreciated

Thanks,
Barak

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more? How will knowing the batch size help you?

Comment: Our SF admin would like to know the batch size the IER records are being synced in order to optimize existing processes running in SF (modify their batch size accordingly). Thanks